# Check if a NuGet Package is compatible with Package Reference style

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I want to update my solution to use the NuGet Package Reference style[1] (as opposed to using packages.config).  There are some compatibility issues[2] that can affect this transition.

- Is there a way to easily what packages in my solution might suffer from compatibility issues, or do I have to do this manually?

[1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/nuget/consume-packages/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference

[2] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/nuget/consume-packages/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference#package-compatibility-issues

Comment: The link you posted say "The migrator analyzes and detects such issues." Do you ave any indication that this is wrong?

Comment: No, I don't (and hadn't noticed that bit of text - thanks!).  I was planning to do some analysis upfront to better plan the migration. Might be a case of try it and see!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to easily what packages in my solution might suffer
>   from compatibility issues, or do I have to do this manually?

In fact, when you migrate all installed nuget packages from `packages.config` to `PackageReference`, there will be no error during the process. The compatibility issue you mentioned is only for the nuget packages that will be installed later in the project, in the new form of [PackageReference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files).

So if you just care about these installed nuget package, I think you do not need to worry about this.If you want to install new nuget packages after migration, I think you should note these below:

**1)** If you want to install a **.Net Framework** nuget package which you created yourself, you need to be careful about **the Package compatibility issues** and these are known issues which are provided by **Microsoft**. They are looking for a solution to this compatibility, so please be patient. For now, you can try the following tips:

**First**, If you want to add some extra files into the new project by nuget, `Packages.config` format will read the **Content** folder and copy its files into the new project while `PackageReference` will copy files from the folder called **ContentFiles**. So you should add these files in `xxxx.nuspec` to pack these files into **ContentFiles** folder.

```
<package >
  <metadata>
     .....
 <contentFiles>
  <files include="xxxx\xxxx" buildAction="content" copyToOutput="true" flatten="true" />
  </contentFiles>
</metadata>
<files>
<file src="xxxx\xxxx" target="ContentFiles\any\any" />
<file src="xxxx\xxxx" target="Content" />
</files>
</package>
```

**Second**, `PackageReferencce` does not support `install.ps1` or `uninstall.ps1`. And if you create some nuget packages, please do not use them.

Therefore, when you create the nuget packages, you should notice these and avoid these points.

**2)** If you install some nuget packages from the [nuget gallery](https://www.nuget.org/), you can check the nuget dependencies in the **manage nuget package UI**.See this:

[image]

Basically, if these nuget packages support `.NetStandard` at the same time, which means you can install it by using either `PackageReference` or `Packages.config` format with any errors.

Hope it could help you.